# Is it possible to have an IF statement in sphinx.conf?

Tags: sphinx

I have Sphinx installed on my development machine as well as my production sever, so my sphinx.conf has stuff like this:

```
source source_config
{
    #LIVE
    // live server credentials

    #DEV
    // development machine credentials
}
```

So I have to keep one set of credentials and file paths (scattered all throughout the conf file) commented out.

Is there any way to have an IF statement in sphinx.conf so that it can automatically choose which set of credentials and file paths to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well on linux servers at least the config file can be a be an executeable script, eg PHP/perl etc, using a 'shebang' syntax. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

---

```
#!/usr/bin/php

source dbdetails {
    <?php if (trim(`hostname`) == 'liveserver') { ?>
        sql_host = db1.domain.com
    <?php } else { ?>
        sql_host = localhost
    <?php } ?>
    sql_user = ...
}

source index1 : dbdetails {
    # no need to repeat sql_host here, as inheritied from master source
    sql_query = ...
}
```

---

Example also shows inheritence, so only need to have one common source block.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Typically you have to use different confs. One approach is to use a higher level language, E.g. Python or PHP to build the conf.

I'm using Sphinx in Django (Python), and also had this problem. Solved it using a Python implementation that outputs the .conf file. See e.g. [here](https://github.com/jorgecarleitao/django-sphinxql/blob/master/sphinxql/configuration/configurations.py).